# Automatically Detect the Dongle Port Number C#

Tags: c#, winforms, sms, port, dongle

My client wants a simple C# WinForms application to send SMS messages over the Huawei E303 dongle. I used the below code and it works successfully.

```
public class SMSSender
{
    SerialPort sp = new SerialPort();

    public bool SendMessage(string PhoneNumber, string Message, int port)
    {
        string selectedPort = String.Concat("COM", port);

        sp.PortName = selectedPort;
        sp.Open();

        PhoneNumber = char.ConvertFromUtf32(34) + PhoneNumber + char.ConvertFromUtf32(34);
        sp.Write("AT+CMGF=1" + char.ConvertFromUtf32(13));
        sp.Write("AT+CMGS=" + PhoneNumber + char.ConvertFromUtf32(13));

        sp.Write(Message + char.ConvertFromUtf32(26) + char.ConvertFromUtf32(13));
        sp.Close();
    }
}
```

But the problem is, this code does not detect the dongle port number automatically. I cannot hard code the port number because when he connect the dongle to a different USB port, then port number changes. As a simple solution, I added a text box to enter the port number manually.

Can anyone help me to improve this code to automatically detect the dongle port number?

Comment: Best I can think of is to enumerate all the COM ports and send an AT command that identifies the dongle. If the COM port responds correctly, you've found the port.

Comment: @RonBeyer: I think that is the answer. Why don't you add it as an answer?

Comment: I would guess you could narrow down the set of COM ports by using " new ManagementClass("WIN32_SerialPort")" ?

Comment: Thanks friends for your valuable comments. I will try out your solutions.